# as3 countdown timer with setting a different starting amount

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey guys i am a newbie in action script 3 this is my code can anyone help me figure out how i can get it to reset back to the original starting set time each round or level.

this is my variables

```
private var seconds:int = 60;
private var minutes:int = 10;
private var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(10);
private var secString = "00";
private var minString = Number(minutes);
```

this is the levels information i am grabbing to display.

```
private var levels:Array = [
["01", "25", "50", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["02", "50", "100", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["03", "75", "150", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["04", "100", "200", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["05", "150", "300", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["06", "200", "400", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["07", "250", "500", "No Ante", "25", "50", "100", "500", "1000"],
["08", "300", "600", "No Ante", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["09", "400", "800", "No Ante", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["10", "500", "1000", "100", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["11", "600", "1200", "200", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["12", "700", "1400", "300", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["13", "800", "1600", "400", "100", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000"],
["14", "900", "1800", "500", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000", "25000"],
["15", "1000", "2000", "1000", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000", "25000"],
["16", "3000", "6000", "2000", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000", "25000"],
["17", "5000", "10000", "5000", "500", "1000", "5000", "10000", "25000"]
];
```

this is my levels or round for each level the timer needs to be reset back to the starting time and countdown

```
private var levelindex:int = 0;
```

this is my timer functions with is not working well

```
private function countTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
if (seconds > 60) {
} else {
    seconds--;
    // minus one minus every 59 sec
    if (seconds == 59) {
        minutes--;
    }
    secString = String(seconds);
    minString = String(minutes);

    // sec under 10 gets a 0 in front
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secString = String("0" + seconds);
    }

    // minutes under 10 gets a zero in front like 00:09
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minString = String("0" + minutes);
    }

    // reset seconds back to 60
    if (seconds == 0 && minutes >= 1) {
        seconds = 60;
        if (minutes == 0) {
            minuteStored = minutes;
            nextRound();

        }
    }

    if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
        if (levelindex == 17) {
            trace("Game Over")
            myTimer.stop();
        }
        trace("Round Over now reset and move to next round")
        minuteStored = minutes;
        nextRound()

    }

}

// this is to convert it to a string text
master.pages.timerMc.timerTextMc.goldTextMask.numberField.text = minString + ":" +    secString;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you give a brief summary of what your code is supposed to do and how it is failing. It may seem obvious to you, but you will have a better chance of getting your question answered if people can quickly understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is this Flash Builder or Flash Pro?

Comment: I am actually using Intellij do you know it its really good for as3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often I'll use a CountdownTimer class that extends Timer.

This timer can be instantiated by specifying total time and interval in milliseconds.

For example, to countdown from 5-minutes at 1-second intervals:

```
var countdownTimer:CountdownTimer = new CountdownTimer(5 * 60 * 1000, 1000);
```

At the start of each level, instantiate a new countdown timer for the desired total time:

```
protected function startLevel():void
{
    countdownTimer = new CountdownTimer(5 * 1000 * 60);
    countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
    countdownTimer.start();
}
```

On each timer event, obtain the remaining time applying your formatting:

```
protected function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    var minutes:int = countdownTimer.time / 60000;
    var seconds:int = (countdownTimer.time / 1000) % 60;

    trace((minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes.toString() : minutes.toString()) + ":" +
          (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds.toString() : seconds.toString()));
}
```

When the timer counts down to zero, use the `TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE` handler:

```
protected function timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace("time's up!");
}
```

At the end of your level, reset the timer:

```
protected function endLevel():void
{
    countdownTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    countdownTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
    countdownTimer.reset();
}
```

CountdownTimer class implementation:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class CountdownTimer extends Timer
    {

        public var time:Number = 0;

        public function CountdownTimer(time:Number=Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY, delay:Number=1000)
        {
            super(delay, repeatCount);

            if (isNaN(time))
                this.time = 0;
            else
                this.time = time;

            repeatCount = Math.ceil(time / delay);
        }

        override public function start():void
        {
            super.start();

            addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
            addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
        }

        protected function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            time -= delay;
        }

        protected function timerCompleteHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
        }

        override public function stop():void
        {
            super.stop();

            removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
            removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much I have to go home and try it out I am still new to programming. I still have all my code on one document classing :S I must figure out how it works talking to from one document class to an other. I really appreciate you taking your time to help me out.

Comment: Do you think its possible to add like comments within your code what does what? like the timerHandler i didn't understand what time -+delayl means?

Comment: It's counting down.  Paste the `CountdownTimer` class to a file.  Details relevant to your implementation are how to use the timer.

Comment: I actually got it to work I am just trying to figure out how to pause it now and and i'm researching new code that i had never seen or used before but it got to work with my art Thank you so much I am learning so many things just by read a pros code and to see how you've done it.

Comment: Pause should work calling `stop()` and resume with `start()` - just be sure not to call `reset()` if you're trying to pause.  Thanks, all the best!

Comment: Hey Jason so like i said i did get it to work but it still has the same problem i had last time where when the countdown reaches 00:00 the level var goes up by 1 but it doesnt reset properly and i can't figure out why plus it doesnt reach 00:00 it gets to 00:01 and stops

Comment: Hi Jason i am testing and tracing with in functions it seem like if the app is running at slow frame rate the timer will be effected right ? and i also wanted to know how can i make the timer go faster for testing i am playing with the numbers but it seems to be going at frame rate

Comment: I'll put together an example later this evening.

Comment: Hey Jason i added a reset to your code but i would like to be able to set different time to the countdown timer plus it does the same problem i had with my old countdown timer where it doesnt reset back to zero and restarts the countdown a the next level

Comment: Here's an example counting down level by level.  I don't use IntelliJ, so create a new project running [CountdownExample.as](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/CountdownExample.as) using the timer class [CountdownTimer.as](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/countdown-timer/CountdownTimer.as).