# Countdown Timer in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, countdown

I'm testing the opposite script as a countdown timer, and there's a type error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@33d6b881f29 to flash.events.TimerEvent.

```
var goalTimerScore: int =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 20;
var Minutes:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
var Seconds:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60);
timerMin_txt.text = String(Seconds);
timerSec_txt.text = String(Minutes);

timerWatch.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countTimer);
timerWatch.play();

function countTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if (timerWatch.currentFrame == 61) {
        Seconds--;
        if (Seconds > 59) {
            Seconds = 0;
            timerSec_txt.text = "0" + Seconds;
            Minutes--;
            if (Minutes > 10) {
                timerMin_txt.text = "" + Minutes;
            } else {
                timerMin_txt.text = "0" + Minutes;
            }
            if (Minutes == 0 && Seconds == 0) {
                timerWatch.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countTimer);
                timer.stop();
                gotoAndPlay("gameover_Hidden3");
                return;
            }
        } 
        else {
            if (Seconds >= 10) {
                timerSec_txt.text = "" + Seconds;
            } else {
                timerSec_txt.text = "0" + Seconds;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Look at `(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countTimer)`... Which says **countTimer** is an **Enter Frame event**. It cannot later be changed and used as a **Timer event** like in the function `countTimer (e:TimerEvent)`. Your event must setup in code as: `(TimerEvent.TIMER, countTimer);` .

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong function parameters, they should be:

```
function countTimer(e:Event):void {
```

As a suggestion, running a timer off the frame rate can be pretty inconsistent as it relies on a constant frame rate. Probably better to use a time based approach.

You can use the `Timer` class for a basic approach. There is an example in the asdocs of a count down.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html

Comment: Got it! Except I have a problem minutes and seconds coding...

Comment: Any ideas how to solve this for the countdown in Minutes and Seconds?

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? Are you having issues converting from seconds to mm:ss ?

Comment: It's a similar to the timer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71570004/counttime-in-as3

Comment: Using the same text fields: timerMin_txt.text = String(Seconds);
timerSec_txt.text = String(Minutes);

Comment: Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You'll have to elaborate some more, I'd suggest posting a new question with where your code is at now. or editing this one if it's still close.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720876/as3-countdown-timer-with-setting-a-different-starting-amount

Answer (score 0):

```
function countTimer(e: Event): void {
    if (timerWatch.currentFrame == 61) {
        Seconds--;
        if (Seconds < 0) {
            Minutes--;
            Seconds = 59;
        }

        if (Minutes == 0 && Seconds == 0) {
            timerWatch.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, countTimer);
            timerWatch.stop();
            gotoAndPlay("gameover_Hidden3");
            return;
        }

        if (Minutes >= 1 && Seconds == 0) {
            if (Minutes == 0) {
                timerMin_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
                timerSec_txt.textColor = 0xFF0000;
            }
        }

    }
    if (Seconds < 10) {
        timerSec_txt.text = "0" + Seconds;
    } else {
        timerSec_txt.text = "" + Seconds;
    }
    if (Minutes < 10) {
        timerMin_txt.text = "0" + Minutes;
    } else {
        timerMin_txt.text = "" + Minutes;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A crucial thing for timer accuracy is the `stage.frameRate` property. Without maxing it out, accuracy will be multiples of 60 Hz.

```js
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;

stage.frameRate = 1000;

const t:Timer = new Timer(0);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, t_h);
t.delay = 10000; //10 seconds
timestamp = getTimer();
t.start();

public function t_h(e:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("countdown complete")
    trace(getTimer() - timestamp)
    t.stop();
}
```